# Angular mat table rows are not displaying the right data in a column with asynchronous code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to update and display a property row in a mat table when one of the property row has data. It is working when I set hardcode synchronous data, but it is not when I set asynchronous as a promise. The rows appear updated only when use the pagination step forward and go back to the previous code. Here is the code (it is not the full code and I need to make this works with the asynchronous code):

```
@ViewChild(TableGeneratorComponent)
  tableGenerator!: TableGeneratorComponent<RateCostCardResultsDto>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.formGroup.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy$))
      .subscribe((valueChanges) => {
        this.tabsService.patchActiveTabContext({
          formValues: valueChanges,
        });
      });

    this.tableGenerator.currentDataSource.connect().subscribe((data) => {
      data.map(async (prop) => {
        if (prop.eventNo && !prop.evtDescription) {
          prop['evtDescription'] = 'test'; // WORKING 
          const event = await this.eventsService
            .getEventByNo(prop.eventNo)
            .pipe(first())
            .toPromise();
          prop['evtDescription'] = event.description; // NOT WORKING
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

mixing `map` and `async and await` always is a bad idea, you can instead go for `forkJoin` without converting the observable to an array, this will do the same logic!

*One concen is that, you are mapping the data to any variable after all the transformations are done! so I am assingning it to a variable called test!

```
test = [];
...
    ...
    this.tableGenerator.currentDataSource.connect().pipe(
      // we can use switchMap to subscribe all at once on one stream!
      switchMap((data) => {
          const promiseObsArr$ = data
            // filter out the unnecessary values!
            .filter((prop) => prop.eventNo && !prop.evtDescription)
            // no need to convert to promise, we can directly use an observable!
            .map((prop) => this.eventsService
                .getEventByNo(prop.eventNo)
                .pipe(
                     first(),
                     map((event) => {
                         prop['evtDescription'] = event.description;
                         return prop;
                     }),
                ));
            return forkJoin(promiseObsArr$);
      }),
    ).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.test = response;
    });
    ...
```